# Floating divs with different heights properly

Tags: html, css, list, styles

I cant get my list items to display properly!

I want it to be like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKv5O.jpg

Right now it is looking like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssJIs.jpg

I know there is a "name" for this but i cant find it so i started this question, please help!

HTML:

```
    <li>
    <img src="http://vinebox.co/proxy/http___v.cdn.vine.co/r/thumbs/11F2FCA00E1016207155612794880_19600f95230.4.4.10195081721815085090.mp4_dzi7hfWQ0FtLGkGihe1TIN.TpZVQEoRCKTMZ_HkMtwN93uiELhX20LOXy4v7.46M.jpg">
       <a class="user-link" href="#">ChrisChin<span class="date">8h</span></a>
       <span>
            Come say hi to us on Omegle!
       </span>
    </li>
```

CSS:

```
.vines ul {}

.vines ul li { 
background:#FFF; 
width:180px; 
display: inline-block; 
padding:10px; -webkit-box-shadow:  1px 1px 2px 0px #dcdcdc; 
border-radius: 3px;        
box-shadow:  1px 1px 2px 0px #dcdcdc; margin:15px; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to set `vertical-align:top` but this is not what you want. your template is row designed but what you want is column design. so you need to change your html.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need some JavaScript to make that structure without caring about every element's height. 
Check out Masonry (http://masonry.desandro.com/), I think it'll work out pretty well.
It doesn't even need jQuery.